# Heroku run rake db:migrate Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ io_fillbuf - fd:9 /app/.fog

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Hi all so after pushing my code to Heroku, i am currently unable to run `heroku run rake db:migrate` and this is the error i am getting.

`rake aborted
Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ io_fillbuf - fd:9 /app/.fog`

To provide some context, i am using fog-google to support media uploads in production.

In `config/initializers/fog.rb` the code is as follows

```
GoogleStorage = Fog::Storage::Google.new(
  :google_project => 'XXXX',
  :google_client_email => 'XXXXX',
  :google_json_key_location => Rails.root.join('.fog/XXXX'),
  :google_storage_access_key_id => ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  :google_storage_secret_access_key => ENV['GOOGLE_STORAGE_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

My google_json_key_location is saved in a `.fog` folder. I'm not sure if that's what is causing the error because heroku can't find the file since the .fog folder is not uploaded onto my Git Repo. But i'm not quite sure where else should i be saving my JSON Private Key file as i think it shouldn't be something uploaded onto my git repo?

EDIT:
I amended the folder from `.fog` to just `fog` so now i am able to run `heroku run rake db:migrate`

The problem is that i'm quite sure i shouldn't be saving this file onto my git. What is an alternative solution for saving this file privately and still being able to access it on heroku?

All help and advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you so much!